# How can I set <HTML> attribute without jQuery

Tags: javascript

I want to set attributes to  tag without jQuery.

I have to set this dynamically.

I understand in jQuery you just do $('html') but without jQuery, I tried `Document.getElementById('html')` but does not work.

How can I do this?

Comment: Is your problem setting an attribute or selecting the right element(s)? Please be clear about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the general case, the standard DOM equivalent to `jQuery('element_name');` is `document.getElementsByTagName('element_name');`. Note that it returns a *NodeList* (which is like an array) and not just an *HTMLElementNode*.

The HTML element, as the root element, can be accessed via `document.documentElement`.

Setting attribute values can be done with the `setAttribute('attribute_name', 'attribute_value');` method on an *HTMLElementNode*. The method is buggy in older versions of Internet Explorer, so you may wish to use the equivalent DOM property instead.

For example, to replace the value of the `class` attribute:

```
document.documentElement.className = "foo bar baz";
```

Comment: While `document.documentElement` is equivalent, `document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0]` would be closer to jQuery's version I think (but I haven't trawled through its selector engine to find out).

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].setAttribute('name','value');
```